# Concatenate two or more variables using Pandas to create a new variable

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Input dataset:

```
Var1     Var2   Var3    Var4

101 XXX       yyyy   12/10/2014

101  XYZ      YTRT  13/10/2014

102  TTY       UUUU  9/9/2014

102  YTY      IUYY   10/10/2014
```

Expected dataset:

```
Var1     Var2   Var3    Var4         New_Variable

101 XXX       yyyy   12/10/2014       XXX, yyyy

101  XYZ      YTRT  13/10/2014        XYZ, YTRT

102  TTY       UUUU  9/9/2014         TTY, UUUU

102  YTY      IUYY   10/10/2014       YTY, IUYY
```

How can I concatenate two or more string variables and create a new variable capturing the concatenated values in the same dataset?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cat` method.

Here's an example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['x','y','z'], 'b': ['x','y','z'], 'c': ['x','y','z']})
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  x  x  x
1  y  y  y
2  z  z  z
```

Now you can create a new column using the `cat` method on one of your chosen columns. Specify the other columns you'd like to concatenate with the `others` argument and your delimiter with the `sep` argument:

```
>>> df["new"] = df.a.str.cat(others=[df.b, df.c], sep=', ')
>>> df
   a  b  c      new
0  x  x  x  x, x, x
1  y  y  y  y, y, y
2  z  z  z  z, z, z
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I am getting following error on using the cat function, could you help me on it?                                                             File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 86, in _length_check
    raise ValueError('All arrays must be same length')
ValueError: All arrays must be same length

Comment: @user3738411 No problem at all. The error suggests that the columns you're trying to concatenate aren't all the same length (they need to be to use `cat`). Does this seem possible to you?

Comment: could you guide me on it? a way to alter the length of existing variables

Comment: @user3738411 If the columns are from the same DataFrame, they should be the same length (i.e. same number of rows). For the example in your question, `df.Var2.str.cat(others=[df.Var3], sep=', ')` should work fine.